# boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context: is not returning accurate expected UILabel size

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, width, uilabel

I am programming an iPhone app, in which I am creating a UILabel with dynamic content at runtime. I have no control of the content of UILabel and therefore I have to calculate its size so I can later use those size values to setup some UI constrains.

I am using the following code to create the UILabel and calculate its expected size:

```
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:20];
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
titleLabel.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vulputate venenatis justo in ultrices. Pellentesque eu pharetra elit, id faucibus mi.";


//Calculate the expected lable size
CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
CGFloat contentWidth = applicationFrame.size.width - 20; // 20 is 10+10, a margin of 10 from each side

CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(contentWidth, FLT_MAX); // FLT_MAX here simply means max possible height

CGRect expectedLabelSize = [titleLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize
                                                         options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                                      attributes:@{
                                                                   NSFontAttributeName:titleLabel.font
                                                                   }
                                                         context:nil];
```

When I run the code above, the value `expectedLabelSize.size.width` is sometimes larger than the original `contentWidth` value passed into `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:`. How do I make sure that `contentWidth` is the max width? This is important, because I am using those values in certain constraints later, and it is important that this max width stays the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the double = when you want to init contentWidth is causing the problem?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but unfortunately no, this is an error that happened here when I am editing the question I was writing. Checked my code and it is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Apple's reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:), there is an interesting discussion:

> This method returns the actual bounds of the glyphs in the string.
>   Some of the glyphs (spaces, for example) are allowed to overlap the
>   layout constraints specified by the size passed in, so in some cases
>   the width value of the size component of the returned CGRect can
>   exceed the width value of the size parameter.

That should be what your are looking for. Is the result width a lot bigger than the "maximum" you are giving? If not I guess the discussion answer you.

Comment: It is not much bigger, maybe by a couple of pixels or three. However this affects the whole layout. If this however is only due to white space, then I do not think it will cause a problem, as I will set the fixed max width, and therefore truncated white space won't cause a problem.